# How can I prevent the default value of DateTimeOffset from being inserted?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm using Entity Framework Core 3.1.7 and created an entity called `Event`, which I set up like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset FirstOccurred { get; set; }
}
```

The entity configuration looks like this:

```
builder.Property(e => e.FirstOccurred)
    .IsRequired();
```

I use my `dbContext` to persist the entity like this:

```
await dbContext.Events.AddAsync(new Event());
```

In this scenario, I was incorrectly expecting that an exception would be thrown at the Database level because the value can't be null.

What actually happens is: the entity is happily persisted with `FirstOccurred` set to  `0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00`

This makes sense, because the default value of `DateTimeOffset` is used.

Now my question: **How could I improve my design to prevent this default value from being inserted?**

Some ideas I had already:

1. Leave the above code as is, but make sure that wherever the entity is used, I'm setting the values correctly. Downside: no guarantee that this will be applied consistently in a team over time.
2. Make `DateTimeOffset` nullable, which in the above `AddAsync()` call would actually cause an SQL exception. Downside: At first glance, `DateTimeOffset? FirstOccurred` might be confusing because the actual DB constraints don't allow null
3. Remove `set;` for `FirstOccurred` and create a constructor that requires this property to be set, e.g. `new Event(DateTimeOffset.Now)`

Comment: "I would expect that an exception is thrown at the Database level because the value can't be null." It's not null, though. You've created a new instance of `Event` which declared its `FirstOccurred` property. Since that property is non-nullable, it was set to `default(DateTimeOffset)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will rephrase my assumption slightly to clarify what I wanted to say here. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with your last idea.

> Remove `set;` for `FirstOccurred` and create a constructor that requires this property to be set, e.g. `new Event(DateTimeOffset.Now)`

It doesn't make sense to track an Event without the timestamp and it certainly doesn't make sense to use the default value for the timestamp.

Changing your model to require a value for the timestamp ensures that you are not writing default data to the record and prevents confusion from seeing a nullable model field when the corresponding table column is non-nullable.

```
public class Event {
    public Event (DateTimeOffset firstOccurred) { FirstOcurred = firstOcurred; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset FirstOccurred { get; set; }
}
```

Just a note from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors), don't remove the `set;` accessor, just mark it `private` if you don't want the value to change after construction.

> Once properties are being set via the constructor it can make sense to make some of them read-only. EF Core supports this, but there are some things to look out for:

> Properties without setters are not mapped by convention. (Doing so tends to map properties that should not be mapped, such as computed properties.)
> Using automatically generated key values requires a key property that is read-write, since the key value needs to be set by the key generator when inserting new entities.
> An easy way to avoid these things is to use private setters.

Of course, you could also maintain the flexibility of the parameter-less constructor by overriding the default value for the property.

```
public class Event {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset FirstOccurred { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
}
```

Comment: I think what you wrote makes a lot of sense, thank you. I'll leave this question open for a few more days and if no other answers appear, I'll mark it as "accepted"